# In synopsys VCS, how can I get the raw RTL verilog output file?

Tags: verilog, synopsys-vcs

I need the VCS preprocessor output. Theres a way to get a verilog file where all params and macros are filled in from the preprocessor. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer online. vppreproc command will flatten all macros/defines.

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Verilog-Perl/vppreproc

Answer (score 1):

In vcs you can use the -Xman=28 qualifier. It will generate a token file with expanded macros.

From the manual:

> Produces a mangled version of input, changing variable names to words from list. Useful to get an entire Verilog design into a single file. Output is saved in the tokens.v file. You can substitute -Xman for -Xmangle.
>   The argument number can be 1, 4, 12, or 28:
>   -Xman=1
>   Randomly changes names and identifiers, and removes comments, to provide more secure code.
>   -Xman=4
>   Preserves variable names, but removes comments.
>   -Xman=12
>   Does the same thing as -Xman=4, but also enters, in comments, the original source file name and the line number of each module header.
>   -Xman=28
>   Does the same thing as -Xman=12, but also writes at the bottom of the file comprehensive statistics about the contents of the original source file.